How do I write script for my bolt slack app deployment on AWS with serverless?
Manually installing AWS and serverless and configuring that with terminal, I want to automate this process by writing a script in Nodejs so that I can run npm run deploy and that will deploy my slack app code to AWS lambda.
Manual process described here.
https://slack.dev/bolt-js/deployments/aws-lambda
I am expecting a script that will automate whole process described in the provided link.
